# improper integral combination

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

This is an example from my textbook
[image]

I'm just thinking why do we have to break the very right-hand side of the integral in red into two parts again, can we make it like
$$\lim_{R_{1} \to{1^{+}},R_{2} \to \infty}\int_{R_{1}}^{R_{2}}\frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, it's because when computing limits like

$$\lim_{R_{1} \to{1^{+}},R_{2} \to \infty}\int_{R_{1}}^{R_{2}}\frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}dx$$

there can be ambiguity over how to compute the limit, e.g. do you take $R_1 \to1$, then $R_2\to\infty$, or do we go in the opposite order, or do we compute them simultaneously (e.g. let $R_1=1+1/t, R_2=t$, and take $t\to\infty$)?

By splitting the integral up, we avoid this problem, as it lets us treat the two limits independently, which is generally simpler.

For an example of why this is important, consider trying to calculate the (divergent) integral $\int_0^\infty\left(2x-\frac{2}{x^3}\right)\,dx$ by the following approaches (as $u\to\infty$):

$$\int_{1/u}^u\left(2x-\frac{2}{x^3}\right)\,dx = 0$$

$$\int_{1/2u}^u\left(2x-\frac{2}{x^3}\right)\,dx = -3u^2+\frac{3}{4u^2}\to -\infty$$

$$\int_{2/u}^u\left(2x-\frac{2}{x^3}\right)\,dx = \frac{3u^2}{4}-\frac{3}{u^2} \to \infty$$

So, any attempts to compute both limits simultaneously requires a bit of care. It's thus often easiest to isolate each limit in a way that allows you to treat them independently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean r1 and r2 go simultaneously. Does the order matter? and also I think only computing both up and down limits simultaneously can make sense.

Comment: @whoisit The problem is that "simultaneously" is ambiguous, and the order very much does matter. You're trying to compute a 2-variable limit, and that's inherently a different matter to a 1-variable limit. How would you go about doing it simultaneously?

Comment: for example $$\lim_{R_{1} \to 1,R_{2} \to 100}R_{2}-R_{1}$$ the limit is 99, isn't it? and I'm doing it simultaneously

Comment: Right, but what would you get for $\lim_{R_{1} \to 1,R_{2} \to 100}\frac{R_2-100}{R_1-1}$? See my edits above to expand upon where this can become a problem.